# Параметризированный url-pattern для servlet-mapping

Tags: веб-программирование, servlet, jsp, java

Вопрос такой. Есть 2 сервлета.  
srv и srv2.

Маппинг такой:

```
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>srv</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>main.srv</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>srv</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/srv/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

   <servlet>
 <servlet-name>srv2</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>main.srv2</servlet-class>
</servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>srv2</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/srv/*/ee</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

К первому можно получиьт досуп через

```
/srv/(что угодно)
```

ко второму я хотел так

```
/srv/(что угодно)/ee
```

С первым работает, а ко второму строго по /srv/*/ee . Как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Вот цитата из Java Servlet Specification 2.5

```
In the web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is used to define
mappings:
• A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ postfix is used
for path mapping.
• A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
• A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of the
application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context
path and the path info is null.
• All other strings are used for exact matches only.
```

Таким образом, звездочка в пути трактуется как wildcard, только если она в его конце или с помощью ее задают все фалы с некоторым расширением. И ответ на ваш вопрос - **никак**.

Однако, конкретный веб-контейнер может поддерживать расширенный синтаксис, и если это так - то вам очень повезло. В таком случае может сработать двойная звездочка (как в Ant скриптах): `/srv/**/ee/*` (но ничего обещать нельзя :)